# Using TableCellRenderer and getColumnClass together

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, abstracttablemodel

when i add getcolumn class to my abstracttablemodel, i couldnt use my custom TableCellRenderer to set background color. (i use this for sorting,alignment numeric columns)

```
public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        Object o = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
        if (o == null) {
          return Object.class;
        } else {
          return o.getClass();
        }
      }
```

This is full of my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DemoRenderer extends JFrame {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        DemoRenderer frame = new DemoRenderer();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public DemoRenderer() {

                JTable table = new JTable();
                table.setModel(new MyTablemodel());
                table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyCustomTableCellRenderer());

                // Tell the table what to use to render our column of doubles

                table.repaint();
                //table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new DecimalFormatRenderer() );                
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

}

/**
         Here is our class to handle the formatting of the double values
         */

class MyCustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

    private static final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat( "#0.00" );

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, 
             Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if(column==1) obj = formatter.format((Number)obj);        
        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    if (isSelected) {
    cell.setBackground(Color.green);
    } 
    else {
    if (row % 2 == 0) {
    cell.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }
    else {
    cell.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    }
    }    
    return cell; 
    }
}

class MyTablemodel extends AbstractTableModel{

    Object[] columnNames = { "A", "B", "C" };
    Object[][] data = {
    { "1abc", new Double(850.503), 53 },
    { "2def", new Double(36.23254), 6 },
    { "3ghi", new Double( 8.3 ), 7 },
    { "4jkl", new Double( 246.0943 ), 23 }};

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }


    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        Object o = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
        if (o == null) {
          return Object.class;
        } else {
          return o.getClass();
        }
      }

}
```

thank you very much for your opinions.

Comment: I haven't seen white color. Its working.

Comment: Why are your overriding `getColumnClass()` method?

Comment: Please can you post some more code because there is no issue in above code.

Comment: i override getColumnClass because i want to sort and align number columns properly, sorting number columns as string provides wrong result. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your getColumnClass() method will return: String.class, Double.class and Integer.class for columns 0, 1, 2.

JTable will provide the default renderer for the Double and Integer columns.

If you want to use your custom renderer for all your columns then you need to do:

```
MyCustomTableCellRenderer renderer = new MyCustomTableCellRenderer();
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer); // or you could use "String.class"
table.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class, renderer);
table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, renderer);
```

When you use "Object.class" it means use the Object renderer as a last resort renderer, only if no other custom renderer for the specific class has been added to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TableColumn#setCellRenderer()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setCellRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer%29) to draw individual values for each column.

Just add below lines in your code

```
MyCustomTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new MyCustomTableCellRenderer();
for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
}
```

instead of

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyCustomTableCellRenderer());
```

and your problem will be solved.

Note: You are using `DefaultTableCellRenderer` that will apply on cell hence use `setCellRenderer()` instead of `setDefaultRenderer()`.

screenshot: (one row is selected)

[image]